# AKS and pod status ContainerStatusUnknown

Tags: azure-aks, containerstatusunknown

I would like to know how AKS handles pods which enter into "ContainerStatusUnknown" status? I assume this is something that happens when control plane can't connect to pod/pod's node (e.g. when spot instance on which it runs has been taken down), what I'm not sure about is whether AKS will be clearing up such pods after some time out or it has to be done manually? If there is a time out, what is the value of it?